# browser compositor issues - chromium versus chrome

Tags: xorg, chromium, gtk, browser

Chrome browser beta release 34 includes the google 'Aura' compositor that caused lots of issues on my env using 12.04 with GPU = intel HD4000.

So, i went back to the 'Chrome-browser' general release and stopped using 'chrome-beta' which i always liked.

Prior to chrome-beta 34 everything with the GPU with WebGL with the GPU drivers was fine.

I do not understand the implications of Google's move to 'aura' compositor on my choice of browser ( chrome or chromium ) for my ubuntu system.

I can just install Chromium browser and try it for awhile and see whether i like it better than chrome browser.

But i am interested in this source divergence around the google 'Aura' compositor and what actually would work better on my linux system??

If google are doing something (fundamental in the aura compositor) with the way that their browser interacts with X  or with GTK i have no idea what i should check in my system to make sure that i have not gummed something up.

I did originally have to twiddle some hardware driver things in Ubuntu in order to get WebGL to work with my GPU (intel HD4000 drivers).

--EDIT-- google-chrome-unstable (M35 including aura) is running fine detls below:

remove older package (stable or beta)

install google-chrome-unstable using apt

open broswer to "chrome://flags" changing first option to "ignore blacklist"

everything looks OK in "chrome://gpu" following tweek above

Comment: I don't know enough about Aura v. GTK to make an answer, but the whole point of them pushing it to beta now is to get the issues you're seeing fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aura hasn't been push to beta. M34 initially was planned to have Aura, but it was decided that there were too many bugs (most likely among other reasons). M35 (currently on dev) **does** have Aura enabled.

Part of the reason that they are switching to Aura is so that they have less code to maintain, fewer #ifdef's (code to compile on one OS, but not on the other), and the ability to push out new features at around the same time as Windows. This does mean that there is probably less reliance on GTK, and the looks of menu entries will be slightly different.

Which one works better? Hopefully, by the time Aura is pushed to beta and stable, Aura will be nearly equivalent in terms of functionality and looks as GTK (note that not everything will be the same; the omnibox drop down menu fills the whole width of the browser rather than just the width of the omnibox, and this is intentional). In terms of performance, Aura *seems* to be a little smoother for me (I'm currently on Chromium Dev), but that's completely unscientific and possibly just a placebo effect. There are one or two major bugs where the rendering is messed up when you exit full screen or shrink the browser window, but I work only in maximized mode and don't see these bugs. On my Intel i3 and HD Graphcs 3000, I don't see any major bugs in Aura.

Note that M34 did suffer from a major rendering bug that affected Intel GPUs where pages would be frozen. The most recent beta release (34.0.1847.60) should have fixed that.

If you want, you can try Chromium Aura from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev), and report any major bugs you see to Chromium.